# File command output is different for same file on diff machine

Tags: linux

I get different output of file command on same file(checked `inode`) from different machines.

One of the machines is with `suse10 sp3` and the another - `rhel4`.

```
machine1>file x.tcl 

x.tcl: ASCII English text

machin2>file x.tcl

x.tcl: data
```

Even in `vi` editor same file look different from different machine. Any clue?
One more thing - there's third machine `suse10 sp3` works fine. Is this machine issue?

Comment: Could it be an utf-8 encoded file in a system without proper unicode support? Hex-edit it and check the first 3 bytes for the BOM.

Comment: Could u please elaborate. how can i be sure that machine don't have proper unicode support

Comment: use md5sum on the file on each machine.

Comment: Output is 
machine1>
41928c7bc7701ebc76cf2dd12ccc738d  x.tcl
machine2>
adb69f0a4d662024a559579735d21e15 x.tcl

Now how can i interpret from this

Comment: If the md5sums are different, then the content is different. The two files are NOT identical.

Answer (score 1):

UTF-8 encoded file sometimes have a few bytes in the beginning called BOM ([byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)). These files may look like binary files in older systems, if the file is pure ASCII English text, just get rid of the BOM.

If the MD5 sum is not the same, then the files are not byte-by-byte identical.

The following oneliner will check the first 3 bytes from x.tcl:

```
python -c 'print open("x.tcl","rb").read()[:3].__repr__()'
```

Comment: ouch, use `head -c 3` or `od -N 3` instead :-)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the `magic` files (used by the `file` command) are different on the two machines.

Try `man magic` on each one, to see where the **magic** files are, and compare the entries (they're usually plain text files).